# What parameter should I use instead of -m in Nohup

Tags: python, linux, terminal, command

I used this command in the past `python3 -m WebBot`, but now I want to run my script using `nohup`.
What should I use instead of -m?

Comment: `nohup` doesn't take -m

Comment: What should I use instead?

Comment: If I understood your post correctly you want to use `nohup` instead of `-m` - is that right? If you want to use `nohup` you should prepend it to your command so `nohup python3 -m WebBot`.